# string gets cut somewhere

Tags: c++, string

I have class with a method:

**Class Strip**

with the header:

```
class Strip : public QMainWindow, public ILog {
```

And the body:

```
void Strip::log(const string& msg) {
  ui->logFeld->append(QString::fromStdString(msg));
  cout << msg << endl;
}
```

Which is implemented from the interface

```
struct ILog {
  virtual void log(const string&) = 0;
};
```

**Caller Class**

In the header file of the calling class the log class is given with:

```
public:
    LoadSetup(ILog *log): log(log) {};
```

In the body of the function is called with:

```
log->log("Error file not found or corrupted");
```

The problem is that `cout` as well as the QElement only shows: `or corrupted`.

Where does the rest of the string get lost or more precisely how can I correct it?

**Valgrind**

`valgrind --leak-check=yes ./Strip > LogFile 2>&1` gives a 12k line big outputfile.

```
 Memcheck, a memory error detector
 Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
 Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
 Command: ./Strip

 Invalid read of size 4
    at 0x6DCD0D3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DCF464: FcConfigFilename (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DE2A15: FcConfigParseAndLoad (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DD8176: FcInitLoadConfig (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DD8265: FcInitLoadConfigAndFonts (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DD8484: FcInit (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x50773D9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1)
    by 0x50049C3: QApplicationPrivate::construct(_XDisplay*, unsigned long, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1)
    by 0x5005283: QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1)
    by 0x40B275: main (in /home/magu_/Strip/Strip)
  Address 0xa0f6814 is 20 bytes inside a block of size 22 alloc'd
    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    by 0x6DCD02C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DCF464: FcConfigFilename (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DE2A15: FcConfigParseAndLoad (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DD8176: FcInitLoadConfig (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DD8265: FcInitLoadConfigAndFonts (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DD8484: FcInit (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x50773D9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1)
    by 0x50049C3: QApplicationPrivate::construct(_XDisplay*, unsigned long, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1)
    by 0x5005283: QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1)
    by 0x40B275: main (in /home/magu_/Strip/Strip)

 Invalid read of size 4
    at 0x6DCD0E8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DCF464: FcConfigFilename (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DE2A15: FcConfigParseAndLoad (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DE30FD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x8FCA6F3: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2)
    by 0x8FCB950: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2)
    by 0x8FC87C6: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2)
    by 0x8FCA17A: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2)
    by 0x8FCD75C: XML_ParseBuffer (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2)
    by 0x6DE2B70: FcConfigParseAndLoad (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DD8176: FcInitLoadConfig (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DD8265: FcInitLoadConfigAndFonts (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
  Address 0xa0fe9d0 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 18 alloc'd
    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    by 0x6DCD02C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DCF464: FcConfigFilename (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DE2A15: FcConfigParseAndLoad (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DE30FD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x8FCA6F3: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2)
    by 0x8FCB950: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2)
    by 0x8FC87C6: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2)
    by 0x8FCA17A: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2)
    by 0x8FCD75C: XML_ParseBuffer (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.5.2)
    by 0x6DE2B70: FcConfigParseAndLoad (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
    by 0x6DD8176: FcInitLoadConfig (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.4.4)
```

...

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
  definitely lost: 8,775 bytes in 44 blocks
  indirectly lost: 18,528 bytes in 555 blocks
    possibly lost: 462,846 bytes in 2,014 blocks
  still reachable: 1,207,255 bytes in 8,462 blocks
       suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
 To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes

 For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
 ERROR SUMMARY: 930 errors from 877 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Okey most of the errors are false positives comming from Qt, I'll try to suppress those errors and try to fix it.

The problem is can't really understand the output. Any further help would be appritiated

Comment: Everything looks fine by me, except that there is no virtual destructor in ILog. Could you provide more code?

Comment: Are there multiple threads logging at once?

Comment: @AlexTelishev. I don't implement a destructor here since there's nothing to cleanup really. I added some more information

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy. I do use pthread's. But I did comment out all call's for log->log without any success. This specifig log->log is called from the main thread. The other threads should anyway not be started at this point

Comment: @magu_ Is this `append` method yours? If yes, post the code. Post a test case!

Comment: Have you tried valgrinding it?

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of errors you have there. It's a miracle your program even works). Read http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.interpret for info about how to interpret vagrind output.

Comment: @AlexTelishev I did try to read it and will further try to make sense out of it. Possibly I did something wrong using `pthread_rwlock_t` and `pthread` I'll further investigate. Thank you for bearing with me

Comment: When I create an interface ILog, derive a class Strip from it, and create a class LoadSetup, then it all works fine. I get the full text. I think we still have too little info or we see not enough of your code. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).